# Database Migration from one version to another using Liquibase

Tags: database-migration, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

I rolled out the first version of application and a Postgres server is set up for the same.

I am planning to roll out my second version of my application which has structural changes in my tables.

For example : I had App table with a column called version , now I have another column called releaseVersion and I have to apply `alter` to add this column.In such a case, how can I use `liquibase` to generate/apply the `migration` script?

Is `liquibase` capable of such `migration`.?

In short, for my first version I created my table using the DDL

```
CREATE TABLE App (version varchar); // I manually generated this using liquibase offline mode and my metadata.
```

Now I have my db with above column.

And I need to generate the alter to add column using `liquibase`. Something like this

```
ALTER TABLE App ADD releaseVersion varchar;
```

Is it possible using `Liquibase` as it is the industry standard for `migration`.

I used `liquibase:diff`, but it is only capable of creating the difference `changelog` from two databases (`target db` and `base db`). In my case, there is only a production database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

Create a changeSet like:

```
<changeSet author="foo" id="bar">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <and>
            <columnExists tableName="App" columnName="version"/>
            <not>
                <columnExists tableName="App" columnName="releaseVersion"/>
            </not>
        </and>
    </preConditions>
    <renameColumn tableName="App" oldColumnName="version" newColumnName="releaseVersion" columnDataType="varchar(100)"/>
</changeSet>
```

and apply it, using `liquibase update` command.

If you need to just add a new column, then your changeSet will look like this:

```
<changeSet id="foo" author="bar">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <not>
            <columnExists tableName="App" columnName="releaseVersion"/>
        </not>
    </preConditions>
    <addColumn tableName="App">
        <column name="releaseVersion" type="varchar(100)"/>
    </addColumn>
</changeSet>
```

Comment: what if "releaseVersion' is my new column and not the old one renamed.

Comment: In this case, you just use `addColumn` tag. I've updated my answer.